# Application is not responding while using animation on Imageview

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-animation

I've a imageview and animating the image infinitely with `YoYo`. I need to start a new activity `AnimalIntroducer` when this imageview is clicked. I can start new activity `AnimalIntroducer` clicking this animated button. But when clicking the back button in `AnimalIntroducer` activity when I come back to my `HomeActivity` then this animation on imageview stops, and button click becomes unresponsive and shows `application is not responding`. Do I have to run the animation in background thread? If so how can I do this?

```java
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);

        hangingMonkeyImageView = findViewById(R.id.monkey_hanging_image_view);

        YoYo.with(Techniques.Bounce)
                .duration(1000)
                .repeat(-1)
                .playOn(hangingMonkeyImageView);

        hangingMonkeyImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,AnimalIntroducer.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to stop the animation on view when the user navigates to the second activity, and restart the animation in onResume() method of HomeActivity.

If you want to learn more about it please see [Android Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)